# How do I set environment variables in Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

I have the below ps code to generate an executable using myfile.spec:

```
python -O -m PyInstaller -v
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('USER', $arr[0])
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PASSWD', $arr[1])
python -O -m PyInstaller myfile.spec --distpath ../dist --onefile -n myfile
```

Contents of myfile.spec:

```
added_files = [
    ('config.yaml', '.')
]

a = Analysis(['myfile.py'],
             pathex=['myfile'],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports = [
               'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime',
             ],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='myfile',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I did a `print(os.environ)` in myfile.py and the env vars for USER and PASSWD are not present. What's the best way to set these variables in the environment to be used by the python file?

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this by using a runtime hook. Just add a `--runtime-hook` option with the path to a .py file.

The documentation says

> --runtime-hook: Path to a custom runtime hook file. A runtime hook is code that is bundled with the executable and is executed before any other code or module to set up special features of the runtime environment. This option can be used multiple times.

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=runtime#cmdoption-runtime-hook

You could use a hook file like this

```py
import os

os.environ["USER"] = <SOMETHING FROM A FILE>
os.environ["PASSWD"] = <SOMETHING FROM A FILE>
```

Keep in mind that saving passwords in files is a security breach. Ideally, your application should ask for a password.

Comment: Note this won't work for `PYTHONHASHSEED`, see [here](https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/7496).

Answer (score -1):

Set the user variables manually in your PC.

---

Go to Environment variables by searching in the start bar or going to `settings-->system--about-->advanced system settings-->environment variables` then in User variables add a new variable with the value you want.

---

Now in your code you can get your variable value by entering `os.environ.get('VariableName')`

Comment: The exe will be installed on user machines so do not have access to local env variables

Comment: @dm2111 what about setting them in the file itself? They probably should work if they are included in the file? for eg. `os.environ["NAME"]="VALUE"` I'm sorry if I am not able to help you.